# How to format Form Data that contains quotes, commas and curly brackets

Tags: locust

I have a data form where the value contains quotes, commas and curly brackets. ("" , {}). How would this be properly formatted for Locust use:

devicePrint: {"VERSION":"2.1","MFP":{"Browser":{"UserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Mobile Safari/537.36","Vendor":"Google Inc.","VendorSubID":"","BuildID":"20030107","CookieEnabled":true},"IEPlugins":{},"NetscapePlugins":{},"Screen":{"FullHeight":735,"AvlHeight":735,"FullWidth":981,"AvlWidth":981,"ColorDepth":24,"PixelDepth":24},"System":{"Platform":"Win32","systemLanguage":"en-US","Timezone":360}},"ExternalIP":"198.200.150.150","MESC":{"mesc":"mi=2;cd=150;id=30;mesc=809641;mesc=827099"}}

deviceCookieName: caData
deviceDNA: 
_eventId: proceed

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about how to express a string with special characters in python code?

I think the simplest is to use triple-quotes, like this:

```
"""my crazy string that contains {} and " and '"""
```